# Is it even theoretically possible to invent coumputers that are more intelligent than humans?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've read an article recently where Stephen Hawking claims that in hundred years there will be computers, which are more intelligent than humans.

Link: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2922442/robotics/stephen-hawking-fears-robots-could-take-over-in-100-years.html

Assuming that would be the case at someday. Wouldn't that mean that those computers could then develop other computers that are again smarter then the original ones. And so on and so on.

That seems somehow irrational to me.

Please share your thoughts with me on this topic.

Comment: Your question is undoubtedly about computers. But where is the science? What is the theoretical definition of intelligence. I do have one that could sustain such a claim, but I do not know that it is shared widely enough,  and it is not really formal enough to sustain definitive assertions. But look at it this way: pretty soon, cars will drive themselves without human intervention. And that will save many lives.

Comment: This site is not a discussion forum; it is for specific, answerable, technical questions.  "Please share your thoughts" is not a suitable question.  Please see our [help], especially http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: The question as stated in the title was resolved a while ago. Playing chess requires intelligence. Computers beat humans at chess.

Comment: AI is what is known in CS as an "open question"... there is a lot of scientific writing on the subject but its not yet "grounded" in fundamental theory which remains to be discovered; see eg kurzweils books/ lectures etc. controversial!